# Special characters when run in netbeans are showing correctly, but when running "jar" file strange characters appear

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, special-characters

Seems like a simple problem, but even after searching forum and web I could not find an answer.  
When I run my program in netbeans all the special characters like **ä, ö, ü** are showing correctly. But when I run "jar" file of the same project (I did clean and rebuild) some strange characters as **@A &$** and so on are appearing instead of correct character.
Any help would be appreciated. 

//edited 22. 08. 2012 00:46
I thought the solution would be easier so I didn't post any code or details. Ok then:

```
//input file is in UTF-8
try {
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fin.dir"));
  String line;
  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    processLine(line, 0);
  }
  in.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
} catch (IOException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

I am displaying characters in this way:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Correct!\n\n" 
  + testingFin.getWord(), "Congrats", 1);`
```

Comment: This is because you are outputting the characters to a device (or terminal emulator, or web page) that is configured to use an encoding different from what your Java program produces.

In this case, your program is writing data encoded in UTF-8 and the program or device on which the output is being displayed either (1) doesn't support UTF-8 or (2) hasn't been told the output is UTF-8.

Without actually seeing your code and a better description of the context in which the output is occurring (terminal, DOS command line, web browser, etc), it will be impossible to provide more help.

Comment: We don't have nearly enough information to know what's going on. We don't know where you're getting the data from, and we don't know how you're displaying it.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I don't think you can really give that much diagnosis yet. It could easily be an *input* problem rather than an *output* problem. We just don't know yet.

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer.  It's clearly an encoding problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison I've added few details hopefully this makes it clear. Pretty basic thing really, just don't know what might be causing the problem. I've tried on different computers, but the same thing happens every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of `FileReader`:

> Convenience class for reading character files. The constructors of
>   this class assume that the default character encoding and the default
>   byte-buffer size are appropriate. To specify these values yourself,
>   construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream.

If you're on Windows, the default encoding is ISO-8859-1, so as Jon commented, the encoding problem is occurring on input. Try this:

```
in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("fin.dir"),"UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your netbeans setting under YOURNETBEANS/etc/netbeans.conf likes this;

```
    -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: I've tried it but it does help. The same problem persists, and I've rebuild and cleaned the program. Also I've rebooted netbeans after I've made changes to conf file.