# Certain characters being displayed differently when program runs from JAR file vs class file

Tags: java, encoding, jar, executable-jar, joptionpane

//

EDIT:
I did some more research and found this regarding changing the default encoding
While it is possible to do so during runtime, it seems that you can only change the defaultCharacterEncoding by properties and not by code, which i think is what i want
I found here that the defaultCharacterEncoding can not be altered during run time :

> Also, one might think they could just alter the system property "file.encoding" programmatically. However, this cannot be set after the JVM starts, as by that time all of the system classes which rely on this value have already cached it.

source: 
http://www.philvarner.com/blog/2009/10/24/unicode-in-java-default-charset-part-4/

Am I interpreting this information correctly?

//

My problem is similar to the one that this user was having, but none of the solutions presented there seemed applicable to my issue:

[Special characters when run in netbeans are showing correctly, but when running "jar" file strange characters appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029455/special-characters-when-run-in-netbeans-are-showing-correctly-but-when-running)

My program displays certain names with special characters such as "Français 6A" or "Español 6A", in a drop-down JOptionPane InputDialog window.

These two names are examples of ones that are displayed correctly when I run my program through my IDE, as seen here:

[image: Dialog - When Run From IDE]

but look like this when I run my program from a JAR file:

[image: Dialog - When Run From JAR]

This is the code that creates the above seen window:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    null,
    "Please choose which class you have. If none of these are correct hit cancel",
    "Class Website Choice",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    dirtyLinks,
    dirtyLinks[0]);
```

and this is the code for the dirtyLinks array:

```
String[] dirtyLinks = new String[dirtyClasses.length];
```

this is the code where dirtyLinks is filled with Strings

```
for (ClassWebsite link : dirtyClasses) {
    System.out.println(i);
    dirtyLinks[i++] = link.getName();
}
```

This is code of the ClassWebsite class

```
public class ClassWebsite {
    private String selfLink = "";
    private String className = "";
    private int distance = 0;
    public ClassWebsite(String className, String selfLink, int distance) {
        this.className = className;
        this.selfLink = selfLink;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return selfLink;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return className;
    }
}
```

dirtyClasses an array of ClassWebsite objects

From reading responses to the questions seen above it seems I have to change the encoding to UTF-8, but I don't know how or where I would do this in my program. If you need more code please let me know.

Comment: do you have an answer to my question? @Perception
and thanks a lot for the edits

Comment: Please post the source code of where you actually read/create/write the strings (in `dirtyLinks`) in question...

Comment: What does `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset())` produce when you run the program outside your IDE?

Comment: i just did thanks for the comment :) @user2758929

Comment: The new code you posted is not helpful in locating the problem. Where are the strings coming from? Post that code. Do you read them from a file, from the web, or did you hardcode them in your java files, or ...?

Comment: @user2758929 i just added it. is that all you need

Comment: @Perception it displays this
cl.ly/image/0b2n3n0P2T40
how can i change the charset to UTF-8
thanks for the help

Comment: @user1702529 - I seriously doubt that was the output of the code I mentioned to you. If anything, that looks like some kind of shortened URL.

Comment: @Perception why would i bother making a whole elaborate detailed question just to spam you with a link... -_-
the output was "MacRoman". that link was a screenshot of the output being displayed through joptionpane

Comment: Why would I want to click on an (external) link that shows the text output when you could have just posted the text output.

Comment: no trust... sigh :(
anyways can you help?
@Perception